# How can I remove extra padding from my footer using CSS?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I would like to set my footer's padding to 0 so that the content of the footer (social media icons) take up the whole footer without extra unnecessary space. I set the padding to 0 but its still giving me a padding. Using bootstrap btw.

here is my html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css"integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf"crossorigin="anonymous" />
<footer class="footer mt-auto py-3 fixed-bottom"> 
  <div class="containerfoot"style="background-color:darkcyan">
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/aiya-siddig/"><i class="fab fa-linkedin linkedln" style="font-size:36px;color:white;margin-right: 10px;"></i></a>
    <a href="https://github.com/aiyasiddig"><i class="fab fa-github github" style="font-size:36px;color:white;margin-right: 10px;"></i></a>
    <a href="mailto:example@outlook.com"><i class="fas fa-envelope mail" style="font-size:36px;color:white"></i></a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

And here is my css:

```
.footer{
       background-color:darkcyan;
       color: cornsilk;
       width: max-content;
       text-align:center;
       position: fixed;
       margin: auto;
       bottom: 0;
       min-width: fit-content; 
       padding: 0;
       
    }

    i {
        margin-left: 50px;
        margin-right: 50px;
        padding: 10px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: white;
        border-radius: 100%;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the class `py-3` and you are set to go